# Delphi: const list of const objects

Tags: arrays, list, delphi, constants

I have KnownFolderPath IDs declared as consts:

```
const
  FOLDERID_LocalAppData  : TGUID = '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}';
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData: TGUID = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';
  FOLDERID_Documents     : TGUID = '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}';
  {...}
```

I want to define an ordered list of folder ids at compile time. I know I can do the following:

```
const
  settings_roots: array[0..2] of TGuid = (
    '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}',
    '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}',
    '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}'
  );
```

But this is not convenient maintainable code so I would like to rather use the names defined before. But this gives me compiler errors in Delphi XE3 (const expression expected):

```
const
  settings_roots: array[0..2] of TGuid = (
    FOLDERID_LocalAppData, FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, FOLDERID_Documents
  );
```

I could define the FOLDERIDs as const strings like

```
const
  FOLDERID_LocalAppData   = '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}';
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';
  FOLDERID_Documents      = '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}';
  {...}
```

but than I would have to convert the ids with `StringToGUID()` everywehere in the code. Isn't it somehow possible to define an ordered static / const list of const objects before runtime in Delphi?

Comment: I disagree that it is an exact duplicate. The asker specifically wants to be able to define the original constants as a TGUID (rather than a string) so that he can use them elsewhere in his program directly, as he states. This additional specification renders the answers given in the original invalid IMHO.

Comment: A simple edit to Ondrej's answer would resolve that. Akin to the addition I just made to Remy's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the ID constants by name in the array declaration, you need to remove the `TGuid` type from the ID constant declarations, making them "True constants" instead of "Typed constants":

```
const
  FOLDERID_LocalAppData = '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}';
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';
  FOLDERID_Documents = '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}';
  {...}
```

This is covered in Embarcadero's documentation:

[Declared Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants)

> True Constants
>
> A true constant is a declared identifier whose value cannot change. For example:
>
> ```
> const MaxValue = 237;
> ```
>
> declares a constant called `MaxValue` that returns the integer 237. The syntax for declaring a true constant is:
>
> ```
> const identifier = constantExpression
> ```
>
> where `identifier` is any valid identifier and `constantExpression` is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing your program.
>
> ...
>
> Constant Expressions
>
> A constant expression is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing the program in which it occurs. Constant expressions include numerals; character strings; **true constants**; values of enumerated types; the special constants `True`, `False`, and `nil`; and expressions built exclusively from these elements with operators, typecasts, and set constructors.
>
> ...
>
> Typed Constants
>
> Typed constants, unlike true constants, can hold values of array, record, procedural, and pointer types. **Typed constants cannot occur in constant expressions**.
>
> ...
>
> Array Constants
>
> To declare an array constant, enclose the values of the elements of the array, separated by commas, in parentheses at the end of the declaration. **These values must be represented by constant expressions**.

It is often useful to declare typed constants as well, which you can do without repeating the values, eg:

```
const
  FOLDERID_LocalAppData = '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}';
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';
  FOLDERID_Documents = '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}';
  {...}

  FOLDERID_LocalAppData_GUID: TGUID = FOLDERID_LocalAppData;
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData_GUID: TGUID = FOLDERID_RoamingAppData;
  FOLDERID_Documents_GUID: TGUID = FOLDERID_Documents;
  {...}

  settings_roots: array[0..2] of TGuid = (
    FOLDERID_LocalAppData, FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, FOLDERID_Documents
  );
```

Alternatively, so the `TGuid` typed constants can match the Win32 API naming scheme:

```
const
  FOLDERID_LocalAppData_STR = '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}';
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData_STR = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';
  FOLDERID_Documents_STR = '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}';
  {...}

  FOLDERID_LocalAppData: TGUID = FOLDERID_LocalAppData_STR;
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData: TGUID = FOLDERID_RoamingAppData_STR;
  FOLDERID_Documents: TGUID = FOLDERID_Documents_STR;
  {...}

  settings_roots: array[0..2] of TGuid = (
    FOLDERID_LocalAppData_STR, FOLDERID_RoamingAppData_STR, FOLDERID_Documents_STR
  );
```

Comment: This way I cannot use the `TGuid` type and its class operators without converting the constants with `StringToGUID()` everywhere.

Comment: @PascalRosin I made an edit that shows how to address that.

Comment: the additional typed constants are looking like the way to go. Thanks @DavidHeffernan

Comment: It might make more sense to name the string constants like `FOLDERID_XXX_STR` instead of `FOLDERID_XXX`, and then drop the `_GUID` suffix from the `TGuid` constants so they match the Win32 API.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly the answer appears to be no. You an do the following

```
const
  FOLDERID_LocalAppData   : TGUID = '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}';
  FOLDERID_RoamingAppData : TGUID = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';
  FOLDERID_Documents      : TGUID = '{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}';

  const
  settings_roots: array[0..2] of ^TGuid = (
    @FOLDERID_LocalAppData, @FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, @FOLDERID_Documents
  );
```

but then you would need to assign like this

```
  iGUID := settings_roots[ i ]^;
```

Not sure if that is acceptable. You could put a class wrapper around it if you wish.

Comment: This is what I meant with _"I could define the FOLDERIDs as const strings"_. But this would mean I have to convert the FOLDERIDs with `StringToGUID()` everywhere.

Comment: @PascalRosin OK

Comment: @Dsm Have a look at Remy's answer to see a neat way around all of this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, neat